# Event-Driven Pattern vs MVC?

Tags: hooks, actions, events, design, mvc

In general terms what is it that the `MVC framework` differs from `Event Driven Pattern`? Is it even comparable?

eg.: *Codeigniter* vs *Wordpress*

I mean while **Codeigniter** uses `MVC` it "watches" the *Model/Controllel/View*,

**Wordpress** watches `events` that happens on the website like *Initializing*(action - init hook), *Admin bar initialization*(action - admin init), *loading the header* (wp_head) etc..

I would like to have more insight on my view on this from a professional, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain it simplest as i can:

**MVC Framework** - Is a framework, that uses [MVC software architectural pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). This pattern sepatares logic in Controller, data in Models, and HTML code in Views. This 3 are separated in different files, so code is cleaner.

[**Event Driven Pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) - Is a software architecture pattern, that promoting the production, detection, consumption of, and reaction to events.

It's 2 separated things. Wordpress don't use MVC pattern, but uses Event Driven Pattern paradigm. But for example [Symfony 3 uses both MVC and Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html).

If you want, you can code some event's like libraries in Codeigniter and use events. You can even use [MVC patter in WP plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48329/how-to-structure-a-plugin) But this solutions are not that great, if they are not in PHP application by default.

Answer (score 0):

They are 2 different pattern. Modern Frmw give you the chance to use both 2. Wordpress since it's a cms software, use event driven pattern (with the famous hooks) to implements function during the execution, anyway it's up to all developers using a mvc oop as well, or a procedural pattern to display the contents. They're 2 pattern which make something different. One is fish, the others is meat.