# How do I create plugin or theme using MVC pattern?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, mvc

I am creating theme for property listing and wanted to create a add-on plugin for admin and front end customization using MVC pattern.Does anyone have any solution for same?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mvc/

Comment: Who is down voting?Is there any custom code solution?I am not looking for plugin supported solution.Thanks

Comment: MVC is a design pattern, the question asked doesn't make a great deal of sense, if you want to use MVC, use MVC, create model view and controller classes and use them

Comment: Run a search for `wordpress plugin template mvc` and read away.

Comment: Do you have solution for same, as I have already mentioned that I am not looking for plugin supported solution.Do you?Thanks

Comment: @shishirmishra montrealist was suggesting you look for a *plugin template* rather than a *plugin* to get a general idea of how to use the pattern in a plugin. If you're familiar with MVC, it really won't be much different from other MVC projects - it boils down to little more than using the pattern, and using the WordPress APIs.

Comment: It's for plugins structure, but check this answers https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48329/how-to-structure-a-plugin